# How to create a query on an existing table and build a table(view) with aggregated data and a restriction?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, qsqlquery

What I have is an MS-SQL database that I use to store data/info coming from equipment that is mounted in some vehicles (1-3 devices per vehicle).

For the moment, there is a table in the database named DeviceStatus - a big table used to store every information from the equipment when they connect to the TCP-server. Records are added (sql INSERT) or updated (sql UPDATE) here.

The table looks like this:
[image]

```
Sample data:   
1040    305 3   8.00    0
1044    305 2   8.00    0
1063    305 1   8.01    1.34
1071    312 2   8.00    0
1075    312 1   8.00    1.33
1078    312 3   8.00    0
1099    414 3   8.00    0
1106    414 2   8.01    0
1113    102 1   8.01    1.34
1126    102 3   8.00    0
```

**Remark**: *The driver console is always related to the device installed on first position (it's an extension of Device on Position 1; obvioulsly there's only one console per vehicle)* - so, this will be some sort of *restriction* in order to have the correct info in the desired table(view) presented below :).

What I need is a SQL query (command/statement) to create a table(view) for a so-called "Software Versions Table", where I can see the software version for all devices installed in vehicles (all that did connect and communicate with the server)... something like the table below:
[image]

**Remark**: Device#1 for 414 is missing because it didn't communicate (not yet I guess...)

Comment: do you only have 3 SW version or an infinite number of SW? A sample that we can copy/paste would be better than a picture. You can use SQLFiddle. Why there is no position 1 for 414 but I can see device1SW VErsion ?

Comment: @JulienVavasseur: Yes, maximum is 3 per vehicle: normally there's one device mounted at each door.

Comment: Instead of 2 random screenshots, you should include a sample of 5-10 `DeviceInfo` and the resulting `SwVersion`. Afaik, more than half the information displayed in `SwVersions` isn't displayed in the `DeviceInfo` table.

Comment: oh, nvm, I just understood where your DriverConsoleVersion is coming from I thought you were grouping by Vehicule+Console. Btw, wrong Julien ;)

Comment: @groenhen So in `DeviceInfo` there will never be more than 3 rows for any given VehicleNo?

Comment: @JulienBlanchard: Absolutly. As I already mentioned: maximum 3 (trois :)

Comment: @groenhen you said maximum 3 software (and thus postitions being 1,2,3), but you didn't mention there can't be duplicate rows. There a massive difference with the problem if there can be duplicates.

Comment: @JulienBlanchard: oh but I did: check above for primary key (DeviceSerial). Moreover, I mentioned the records are added (mandatory for new devices) or UPDATED :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the PIVOT answer, but here is another way:

```
select VehicleNo,
max(DriverConsoleVersion) DriverConsoleVersion,
max(case when DevicePosition = 1 then DeviceSwVersion end) Device1SwVersion,
max(case when DevicePosition = 2 then DeviceSwVersion end) Device2SwVersion,
max(case when DevicePosition = 3 then DeviceSwVersion end) Device3SwVersion
from @DeviceInfo
group by VehicleNo
order by VehicleNo
```

You can also do casting or formatting on them.  So one might be:

```
       select ...,
       isnull(cast(cast(
          max(case when DevicePosition = 1 then DeviceSwVersion end)
            as decimal(8,2)) / 100) as varchar(5)), '')  Device1SwVersion,
```

Comment: I ran it in SQL Fiddle (I'm at home now) and it works. Pretty nice, clean, simple :)  It outputs 0 (zero) for DriverConsoleVersion (which is declared int or smallint in database) for vehicle 414, probably better to have null there, but not critical I suppose. Yes, I'm gonna upvote this answer too. Thx JB for sharing this :)

Comment: Documentation says: CAST ( expression AS data_type [ ( length ) ] ) , so I guess NUMERIC(8, 2) means that the target total length will be 8, of which 2 will be used for decimals...? Decimal point is not counted I suppose...

Comment: if for whatever reason, there is a driver version with position 2 or 3, it could be useful to add case when DevicePosition = 1... to max() drivermonsoleversion

Comment: It seems it works ok even without `order by VehicleNo` (last line). :)

Comment: @groenhen it does work without the ORDER BY, but your order isn't guaranteed to be any order.

Answer (score 2):

With the information we have so far, I think you need a query with a PIVOT:

```
SELECT P.VehicleNo, V.DriverConsoleVersion, P.[1] AS [Device1SwVersion], P.[2] AS [Device1SwVersion], P.[3] AS [Device1SwVersion]
FROM (
    SELECT VehicleNo, [1], [2], [3]
    FROM (
        SELECT VehicleNo, DevicePosition, DeviceSwVersion
        FROM @DeviceInfo
    ) as d
    PIVOT (
        MAX(DeviceSwVersion)
        FOR DevicePosition IN ([1], [2], [3])
    ) PIV
) P 
LEFT JOIN @DeviceInfo V
    ON V.VehicleNo = P.VehicleNo AND V.DevicePosition = 1;
```

You can create a view with such a query.

The first subquery get 4 column for Device 1 to 3 for each vehicle.
It then LEFT JOIN it with the SwVersion table in order to get the Console version associated with Device 1.

**Output:**

```
VehicleNo   DriverConsoleVersion    Device1SwVersion    Device1SwVersion    Device1SwVersion
102         1.34                    8.01                NULL                8.00
305         1.34                    8.01                8.00                8.00
312         1.33                    8.00                8.00                8.00
414         NULL                    NULL                8.01                8.00
```

**Your data:**

```
Declare @DeviceInfo TABLE([DeviceSerial] int, [VehicleNo] int, [DevicePosition] int, [DeviceSwVersion] varchar(10), [DriverConsoleVersion] varchar(10));

INSERT INTO @DeviceInfo([DeviceSerial], [VehicleNo], [DevicePosition], [DeviceSwVersion], [DriverConsoleVersion])
VALUES
    (1040, 305, 3, '8.00', '0'),
    (1044, 305, 2, '8.00', '0'),
    (1063, 305, 1, '8.01', '1.34'),
    (1071, 312, 2, '8.00', '0'),
    (1075, 312, 1, '8.00', '1.33'),
    (1078, 312, 3, '8.00', '0'),
    (1099, 414, 3, '8.00', '0'),
    (1106, 414, 2, '8.01', '0'),
    (1113, 102, 1, '8.01', '1.34'),
    (1126, 102, 3, '8.00', '0')
;
```

Comment: Hmmm, doesn't seem to be ok... Some devices have **SW version 8.01**, they are not present int he output... Maybe '8.0x' will do the job?

Comment: just a data type issue in my sample table. I change it to varchar. it first was int which were rounded to 8.

Comment: What if the DataBase stores the Driver Console version as integer (i.e. 134 -> it actually does...), is there a trick to have it "converted" in the output view as 1.34 wich is more readable for the user?   The DeviceSwVersion I see is - on the other hand - varchar().

Comment: Since 134 / 100 = 1.34 ? you can use: Cast(X as numeric(8,2))/100